# divide image into two parts using divider

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I'm working on one app where I need to divide a image into two part using a red line.

1. left part for labels
2. right part for prices

   [image]

**Question 1.**

How can I draw a red line on image?

**Question 2.**

How can I divide image to two parts using red line ?( red line position is not fixed. user can move the position wherever it want)

**Question 3.**

How can I get line current position and how can I use that position two divide image

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I would approach this in somewhat the same manner as koray was suggesting:

1) I am assuming that your above image/view is going to be managed by a view controller, which I will call *ImageSeperatorViewController* from here on.

Inside of *ImageSeperatorViewController*, insert koray's code in the *-(void) viewDidLoad{}* method. Make sure you change the imageToSplit variable to be an UIImageView instead of a plain UIView.

2) Next, I assume that you know how to detect user gestures. You will detect these gestures, and determine if the user has selected the view (i.e. **bar** in koray's code). Once you  have determined if the user has selected **bar**, just update its origin's X position with the touch position.

```
CGRect barFrame = bar.frame; 
barFrame.origin.x = *X location of the users touch*
bar.frame = barFrame;
```

3) For cropping, I would not use [github.com/bilalmughal/NLImageCropper](http://github.com/bilalmughal/NLImageCropper), it will not do what you need to do.

Answer (score 4):

Try this on for size:

**Header:**

```
@interface UIImage (ImageDivider)

- (UIImage*)imageWithDividerAt:(CGFloat)position width:(CGFloat)width color:(UIColor*)color;
- (UIImage*)imageWithDividerAt:(CGFloat)position patternImage:(UIImage*)patternImage;
- (NSArray*)imagesBySlicingAt:(CGFloat)position;

@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
@implementation UIImage (ImageDivider)

- (UIImage*)imageWithDividerAt:(CGFloat)position patternImage:(UIImage*)patternImage
{
    //pattern image
    UIColor *patternColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage];
    CGFloat width = patternImage.size.width;

    //set up context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //draw the existing image into the context
    [self drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    //set the fill color from the pattern image color
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, patternColor.CGColor);

    //this is your divider's area
    CGRect dividerRect = CGRectMake(position - (width / 2.0f), 0, width, self.size.height);

    //the joy of image color patterns being based on 0,0 origin! must set phase
    CGContextSetPatternPhase(context, CGSizeMake(dividerRect.origin.x, 0));

    //fill the divider rect with the repeating pattern from the image
    CGContextFillRect(context, dividerRect);

    //get your new image and viola!
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}

- (UIImage*)imageWithDividerAt:(CGFloat)position width:(CGFloat)width color:(UIColor *)color
{
    //set up context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //draw the existing image into the context
    [self drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    //set the fill color for your divider
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);

    //this is your divider's area
    CGRect dividerRect = CGRectMake(position - (width / 2.0f), 0, width, self.size.height);

    //fill the divider's rect with the provided color
    CGContextFillRect(context, dividerRect);

    //get your new image and viola!
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}

- (NSArray*)imagesBySlicingAt:(CGFloat)position
{
    NSMutableArray *slices = [NSMutableArray array];

    //first image
    {
        //context!
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(position, self.size.height));

        //draw the existing image into the context
        [self drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

        //get your new image and viola!
        [slices addObject:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    //second
    {
        //context!
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.size.width - position, self.size.height));

        //draw the existing image into the context
        [self drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-position, 0)];

        //get your new image and viola!
        [slices addObject:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    return slices;
}
```

The concept is simple - you want an image with the divider drawn over it. You could just overlay a view, or override `drawRect:`, or any number of any solutions. I'd rather give you this category. It just uses some quick Core Graphics calls to generate an image with your desired divider, be it pattern image or color, at the specified position. If you want support for horizontal dividers as well, it is rather trivial to modify this as such. **Bonus:** You can use a tiled image as your divider!

Now to answer your **primary question**. Using the category is rather self explanatory - just call one of the two methods on your source background to generate one with the divider, and then apply that image rather than the original source image.

Now, the **second question** is simple - when the divider has been moved, regenerate the image based on the new divider position. This is actually a relatively inefficient way of doing it, but this ought to be lightweight enough for your purposes as well as only being an issue when moving the divider. Premature optimization is just as much a sin.

**Third question** is also simple - call `imagesBySlicingAt:` - it will return an array of two images, as generated by slicing through the image at the provided position. Use them as you wish.

**This code has been tested to be functional. I strongly suggest that you fiddle around with it, not for any purpose of utility, but to better understand the mechanisms used so that next time, you can be on the answering side of things**

Comment: This is great. It can help me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For Crop you can try this,

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
CGImageRef tmpImgRef = image.CGImage;
CGImageRef topImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height / 2.0));
UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImgRef];
CGImageRelease(topImgRef);

CGImageRef bottomImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, image.size.height / 2.0,  image.size.width, image.size.height / 2.0));
UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bottomImgRef];
CGImageRelease(bottomImgRef);
```

hope this can help you, :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i already use this code and it work fine. How can I add red line on image and using that how can i divide the image. any reference or idea

Comment: https://github.com/bilalmughal/NLImageCropper.  This may help you. But you have to work on it to manage your cords.

Comment: I have try BFCropInterface and BJImageCropper but this both crop the image not divide the image

Answer (score 3):

if you want to draw a line you could just use a UIView with red background and make the height the size of your image and the width around 5 pixels.

```
    UIView *imageToSplit; //the image im trying to split using a red bar
    CGRect i = imageToSplit.frame;
    int x = i.origin.x + i.size.width/2;
    int y = i.origin.y;
    int width = 5;
    int height = i.size.height;
    UIView *bar = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)] autorelease];
    bar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:bar];
```